# What is the Llama2 number of steps?

Tags: neural-networks, natural-language, adam, llm

Llama2 is pretrained with 2 trillion of tokens: $2\times10^9$, and its batch size is of $4\times 10^6$.

We can calculate the number of steps (times we upgrade the parameters) per epoch as follows:

$$\frac{\text{total tokens}}{\text{batch size}}= \frac{2\times10^9}{4\times 10^6}=500. $$

But in the paper we can find:
"*We use a cosine learning rate schedule, with warmup of 2000 steps, and decay
final learning rate down to 10% of the peak learning rate.*"

As the model is trained by only one epoch, the number of parameter upgrades is 500. This contradicts the statement that we have 2000 steps as warmup. I am not understanding why does it happen.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

They use 2 trillion pre-training tokens ($2\times 10^{12}$), not 2 billion ($2\times10^9$). In that case, the number of pre-training steps would be 500,000 > 2000, so all is well.

Having looked at the technical report, I couldn’t find the claim that the pre-training batch size is 4 million. Could you please point to the page with this claim?

Comment: Oh sorry! I was confused with the spanish billion and trillion that it's different from the english/american ones. The batch size is described in page 6 table 1: "All models are trained with a global batch-size of 4M tokens." Thank you a lot, Arya.